# Drop and Recreate All Database Views

Tags: sql-server, version-control, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, database-schema

**Question**

From SSMS, I can use "Generate Scripts" for views, procedures, and functions, and then save each as a "Single file per object."

How can I generate the correct order to execute the files later, given their dependencies on other views?

**Backstory**

I am attempting to get my database schema under revision control.

For views (and procedures and functions), the page below suggests saving one per file. On an update, all would be dropped then all would be recreated.

Unfortunately, the page never mentions details of how it handles dependencies between views.

> [Versioning Databases – Views, Stored Procedures, and the Like](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/02/02/versioning-databases-views-stored-procedures-and-the-like.aspx)
>
> **One File per Object**
>
> My strategy is to script every view, stored procedure, and function
>   into a separate file, then commit the files to source control. If
>   someone needs to add a new view, they script the view into a file and
>   commit the file to source control. If someone needs to modify a view,
>   they modify the view's script file and commit again. If you need to
>   delete a view from the database, delete the file from source control.
>   It's a relatively simple workflow.
>
> The magic happens when a developer, tester, or installer updates from
>   source control and runs a tool that updates their local database. The
>   tool uses a three step process:
>
> 1. The tool applies new schema changes by comparing the available schema change files to the SchemaChangeLog records in the database.
> 2. The tool will **DROP** all stored procedures, views, and functions in the database.
> 3. The tool will run all of the scripts needed to add the views, stored procedures, and functions back into the database.

Comment: Under the generate scripts part... when you get to `Set Scripting Options` you can click **Advanced** and change the options like *Generate Script for Dependent Objects* and *Script Bindings*. Also, it sounds like you are trying to store these in a GitRepo or something similar. Alex Yates has a lot of blogs on this, I'd be sure to bounce off those lessons learned.

Comment: I have a feeling you have nested views going on here which is why you are concerned about inter-view dependency. This is a performance timebomb. It seems perfectly logical to have views call views but it is a sure fire way to decimate your system performance. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: @scsimon That option didn't seem to create a file listing execution order. It only seemed to add files to generate the tables, which doesn't help me.  I am trying to store these in subversion (where my app code already exists).

Comment: @SeanLange Performance is not an issue yet. With the total number of views being relatively low (under 30), I suppose I could copy and paste the nested views into the calling views and require views never call views. I'm looking for a more universal solution, since views could call functions which could call other functions.

Comment: The "universal" solution is to not use nested views. They are the spawn of the devil honestly. They may perform great for a while but then the plans will change because the data changes and the performance doesn't start degrading, it literally plunges off a cliff and things start timing out all over the place. I had a system like that at one point and it was painful to unravel when the proverbial poop hit the fan. Hopefully your functions are not scalar ones as those too are poor performers.

Comment: Nesting functions (assuming they are inline table valued functions) do not suffer the same performance issues. But when they are nested you can create nightmarish dependency cycles. I don't think there is a way to automate getting them in the right order.

Comment: My suggestion is to generate ALTER scripts and deploy code in the loop until all of it deploys.